# Will Firefox (.deb) be replaced by Firefox (snap) when upgrading from Kubuntu 20.04 to 22.04?

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, kubuntu, firefox, 22.04

If I upgrade from Kubuntu 20.04.5 to 22.04.1 will my .deb version of Firefox be replaced by the snap version?

Will it keep all my settings, history and passwords? Passwords I can export to a .csv, so that would not be the main problem.

Comment: I immediately uninstall all snaps. And then install the ppa version. Details: You also have to reset priorities as shown or it will reinstall the Firefox snap.
https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On 22.04, the `firefox` package is described as transitional deb->snap. Hence yes, the deb version will be replaced by the snap version.

In my case (21.04->21.10) it was snapified upon upgrade, and the settings were kept (i.e. the Firefox profile was copied to the snap namespace).

In your LTS-to-LTS scenario, I’m pretty sure things will work in a similar manner, if not more conservative, but in case you have doubts, you can always copy your FF profiles (`~/.mozilla/firefox`) to a safe place before upgrading, just in case.